# merging dataframes by country and year while the countries are not named the same (for example US,United states )

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, fuzzy-logic

Hello I am trying to drop rows that have in a specific column string that is not a year.
For example [image: here] I have the in last rows year formats that have decimal points or '-'.

I have tried to convert the year column into a string and then drop them using the code below but it only removes the row with 2011-21, the ones with decimal points stay.

```
df.level_1=df.level_1.astype(str)

df.loc[
    (~df.level_1.str.contains("."))
    |~(df.level_1.str.contains("-")),
    :]
```

is there a way to fix this issue ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter all rows where `level_1` contains non digit characters:

```
df[~df.level_1.str.contains('\D')]
```

Comment: thanks a lot ! so this '\D' means digit character right ?

Comment: Precisely the opposite! In regex `\d` stands for any digit while `\D` stands for any non-digit character. This makes sense if you consider the negation at the beginning of the filter: `~`

Answer (score 0):

you can use regex:

```
df['level_1']=df['level_1'].astype(str)
df = df[df['level_1'].str.contains('\d\d\d\d-\d\d',regex=True)]
```

Comment: thank you, this one dropped a lot of rows from the data. However I managed to do it with tranbi's response. thank you